# How to train a network to learn a function using MatConvNet?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to understand how to use MatConvNet to learn a function given I/O pairs for training.

I want to discover a function that maps a 486-dimensional input vector to a 1D output value. However, I am unable to get the network to work properly, I need help locating my mistake. Following are the details of what I have done, please let me know if any other info is needed.

Here is my training data layout as it shows on the matlab commpand prompt (I have 1 million samples for training data):

```
>> imdb.images
ans = 
data: [4-D single]
label: [1x1000000 single]
set: [1x1000000 double]

>> size(imdb.images.data)
ans =
1 1 486 1000000
```

I am using a multi-layer fully connected neural network with one input layer of 486 neurons, one hidden layer with 100 neurons and one output layer with 1 neuron.

I have defined the network using fully connected layers as follows:

```
trainOpts.batchSize = 10000 ;
trainOpts.numEpochs = 100 ;
trainOpts.continue = false ;
trainOpts.gpus = [1];
trainOpts.learningRate = 0.001 ;
trainOpts.numEpochs = 100 ;
trainOpts.expDir = 'xyz' ;

f = 1/100; 
net.layers = {};
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type','conv','weights'{{frandn(1,1,486,100,'single'),zeros(1,100,'single')}},'stride',1,'pad',0);
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type','sigmoid'); 
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type','conv', 'weights', {{frandn(1,1,100,1,'single'), zeros(1,1,'single')}}, 'stride',1,'pad',0);    
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type','sigmoid'); 
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type','nnL2');
```

The function in the loss layer "vl_nnL2" is the L2 loss function. I have added it to vl_simplenn as suggested in https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/issues/15. I have also changed the error estimation in cnn_train to the following:

```
function err = error_sqerror(opts, labels, res) 
predictions = gather(res(end-1).x) ;
if numel(labels) == size(predictions, 4)
labels = reshape(labels,1,1,1,[]) ;
end
error = (abs(labels-predictions).^2);
err = sum(squeeze(error));
```

Here is the plot from the training:

[image]

Can someone point out what I am missing?

Thank you,
Ekta